# Residual plot x axis: predictor or predicted outcome variable?

Tags: regression, residuals

I came across two different definitions of residual plots: sometimes residuals are on the y axis and the predictor of interest on the x axis, and sometimes residuals on the y axis and the predicted value for the outcome variable on the x axis.

Often the plots look similar and they are always interpreted in the same way, but I don't understand how this is possible because it seems like two very different things are being plotted. Is it just a matter of preference which one I use and can I really analyze them in the same way?

Comment: If there’s a single predictor, those two plots are equivalent as the predicted is evidently a linear scaling of the predictor. Otherwise the graphs are different and could both be useful. Some people plot observed response vs fitted response as well. To a perfect calculating mind that gives exactly the same information as residual versus fitted, but I sometimes find it helpful. There are several other plots using residuals.

Comment: With several predictors, the graphs have quite different purposes.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! I have multiple predictors, one of interest and the others just covariates of no interest. If I use the residual plot in order to check if no variable was omitted and there is no heteroscedasticity, it's more useful to plot the predictor on the x axis, is that right?

Comment: If plotting the residuals against a choice between the observed values and the predicted values, remember that OLS regression produces a zero covariance between the predicted values and the residuals by construction, and so covariance between the observed values and the residuals is positive and equal to the variance of the residuals.  Observing this (a positive slope) in the shape of the plot would not be not be useful information (the model already takes it into account) which is why plots against the observed values are typically not used.